# Force wget to download only from HTTPS?

Tags: bash, wget, ssl

```
wget https://skype.com -O - > /dev/null
```

isn't good. I just want to create a short bash script to check that an HTTPS cert is valid or no. i think wget doesn't connects if the cert is invalid. i just need a parameter? to wget to only work on HTTPS! are there any?

Comment: What do you actually want? Check if a certificate is valid, or force `wget` to connect only if a certificate is valid?

Comment: What do you see as a valid cert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purpose, just call wget. It will retrieve the certificate and refuse to connect if the certificate is invalid.

Obviously, if you pass an `https://` URL, wget will connect using HTTPS.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aE2SDXsF

Comment: @LanceBaynes: I don't see any connection between this, your question and my answer.

Comment: y, i see now :) ok, then it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title: Pass `--https-only` to force wget to follow https links exclusively. This can be useful for sites that silently downgrade connections to insecure ones.

Comment: The [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) says about `--https-only`: "When in recursive mode, only HTTPS links are followed." This sounds like this argument is ignored when retrieving a single file.